# Criar função em javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função que em tese é pra fazer uma verificação se a variável `x` é igual a variável `y`.

```
function teste(x){
   if (x == 'y*') {
     alert('igual')
   } else {
     alert('diferente')
   }

}
```

Quero que verifique se é `y` e se começar com `y`. Por isso coloquei o `*`, pra pegar tudo que vier depois, porém não funciona.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A comparação `x == 'y*'` só será verdadeira quando `x` for exatamente a *string* `'y*'`, ou seja, dois caracteres sendo um a letra Y e um asterisco.

Se a ideia é verificar se `x` começa com a letra Y, basta utilizar a função `String.prototype.startsWith`:

```
if (x.startsWith('y')) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Outra opção seria usar o metodo [charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

> O método charAt() retorna o caractere especificado a partir de uma
>   string.
>   Se o índice que você fornecer estiver fora do intervalo de índices da
>   string, JavaScript retornará uma string vazia.
>   Se nenhum índice for passado para .charAt(), 0 (zero) será usado por padrão

```
if (x.charAt() === 'y'){
   //...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

O `indexOf` retorna a posição de uma `string` em outra `string` ou *-1* se não encontrar.

```
var s = "foo";
alert(s.indexOf("oo") != -1);
```

Comment: Nesse caso não seria, então, `s.indexOf("y") === 0`?

Comment: `var s = "palavraY";`
`alert(s.indexOf("Y"));` isso vai ter retornar a posição que ele encontra o Caracter caso ele nao encontre ele retorna -1.

Comment: Exatamente, não ficaria mais claro se já adaptasse às necessidades da pergunta?